# PhpStormで、プロキシ経由でSFTPでリモートに接続したい

Tags: php, phpstorm

Phpstormで、プロキシ経由でSFTPでリモートに接続しようとしたとき、以下のエラーが表示され、接続できません。

```
Connection to 'example.com' failed.
Session.connect: java.net.UnknownHostException: example.com
```

調べてみると、下記サイトにあるように、PhpStormはプロキシ経由でのFTPやSFTP接続はサポートしていないとのことでした。

[PhpStorm sftp deploy with SSH Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685426/phpstorm-sftp-deploy-with-ssh-proxy)

しかし、社内で開発している場合など、プロキシ経由でないとリモートに接続できない環境は多いように思います。なんとか接続する方法はないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: PhpStormを実際に使ってないのですが、調べたところ
PhpStormが内包しているJSchのバージョンを差し替えるとうまくいくようでしたのでURL載せておきます。

http://havelog.ayumusato.com/computer/software/e275-jsch_update_to.html

Comment: @shinriyo 回答頂きありがとうございます。ただ、今回、質問させて頂いたのは、プロキシ経由でのSFTP接続がうまくいかないという現象です。プロキシを経由しないLAN内のサーバーにはSFPTで接続できます。